# Patent #6108955 references cited

Tags: patent-infringment

When i look up patent #6108955 on the uspto site it says it is expired due to the maintenance fees not being paid. there is also a list of references cited. They seem to be similar to #6108955 but with slight differences. Do I need to be concerned about those or can I use #6108955 without worrying about infringing on the references cited.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was answered in one of your other questions on this topic but yes, whatever you make, sell, offer for sale, use or import can conceivably infringe on any number of patents that may have come before or after the one in question.